Confidence levels and error rates in binary classification models
I am a beginner self-learning machine learning and I'm currently dealing with a binary classification problem. I made a binary classifier with a basic neural network and I did some experiments with the error rate and confidence interval. It is not a very good classifier, so I want to have a better idea of how much I should trust the result given by the model. Is it a good idea to calculate the possibility of error based on the following result? (Like during inferencing, if my model predicted class 0 with 95% confidence, I can deduce the possibility of error is around 30%) Or this there a better way to approach this? Since It seems a little bit weird to me that somehow 85% confidence has a lower error rate than 95%. Thanks! 

How are you getting the prediction confidence?

I used binary cross entropy with sigmoid activation for my neural network. Then I used the possibility (0 - 1) given by the model and deduced the confidence with abs(0.5 - possibility) * 2.

Neural networks are legendary for giving overconfident probability predictions that do not align with the reality of event occurrence. I have even heard people go so far as to say that the outputs are not even probability values. I find it difficult to go quite that far, but such comments do speak to how poor the predicted probability values often are.
You can assess the quality of the probability values through calibration plots. Scikit-learn has an introduction to this topic as well as implementation code. Even better might be the R tools rms::calibrate and rms::val.prob.
If your neural network does not produce calibrated probability values, which it probably does not, then a literal interpretation of the raw predictions does not make sense, and there is no inconsistency between model confidence and classification accuracy.
Finally, your neural network does not make any classifications on its own, only in combination with a decision rule, such as going with category zero if the raw prediction is below $0.5$ and category one otherwise (common software-default decision rule). As you vary this threshold, you will get different classifications and different classification accuracy values. (Indeed, varying this threshold is how ROC and PR curves are constructed.) These other classifications may better align with the “confidence” values.

You don’t even have to assess classifications, either. Evaluation of the raw predictions is possible and even encouraged in statistics circles.
